# Scrapy: Repeat Response.URL In Each Record

Tags: python, scrapy

The following Scrapy crawlspider is working properly, except for the output of the url (response.url):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class Spider2(CrawlSpider):
    #name of the spider
    name = 'newstl'

    #list of allowed domains
    allowed_domains = ['graphics.stltoday.com']

    #starting url for scraping
    start_urls = ['http://graphics.stltoday.com/apps/payrolls/salaries/agencies/']

    rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=['/apps/payrolls/salaries/.*/$']),
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True),
    ]

    #setting the location of the output csv file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT' : "csv",
        'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/stltoday1.csv'
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #Remove XML namespaces
        response.selector.remove_namespaces()

        #Extract article information
        name = response.xpath('//th[@scope="row"]/text()').extract()
        position = response.xpath('//th[@scope="row"]/following-sibling::*[1]/text()').extract()
        salary = response.xpath('//th[@scope="row"]/following-sibling::*[2]/text()').extract()
        hiredate = response.xpath('//th[@scope="row"]/following-sibling::*[3]/text()').extract()
        url = response.url

        for item in zip(name,position, salary, hiredate, url):
            scraped_info = {
                'url' : item[4],
                'name' : item[0],
                'position' : item[1],
                'salary' : item[2],
                'hiredate' : item[3]
            }
            yield scraped_info
```

The output is displaying 1 character of the URL in each row of the CSV. Any way to make it repeat the entire URL for each record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be zipping `url`, just set it directly:

```
url = response.url
for item in zip(name, position, salary, hiredate):
    yield  {
        'url' : url,
        'name' : item[0],
        'position' : item[1],
        'salary' : item[2],
        'hiredate' : item[3]
    }
```

And, instead of traversing the entire tree multiple times, iterate over the result rows and get the desired information from the context of each item:

```
for row in response.xpath('//th[@scope="row"]'):
    yield {
        "url": url,
        "name": row.xpath('./text()').extract_first(),
        "position": row.xpath('./following-sibling::*[1]/text()').extract_first(),
        "salary": row.xpath('./following-sibling::*[2]/text()').extract_first(),
        "hiredate": row.xpath('./following-sibling::*[3]/text()').extract_first(),
    }
```